# Linux. How to cut line

Tags: bash

I have a problem to split line. 
I have input.

```
echo dat1 dat2 dat3 | tr " " "\n" | xargs -I {} -p ln -s {}
```

I need to get command from line. Output must be:

```
echo    
tr     
xargs
```

I can't use a command awk.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo 'echo dat1 dat2 dat3 | tr " " "\n" | xargs -I {} -p ln -s {}'
echo dat1 dat2 dat3 | tr " " "\n" | xargs -I {} -p ln -s {}

$ echo 'echo dat1 dat2 dat3 | tr " " "\n" | xargs -I {} -p ln -s {}'  | awk '{print $1}' RS='|'
echo
tr
xargs
```

Explanation: `awk`, record separator=`|`, print first field (`$1`) in every record.

grep based answer:

```
$ echo 'echo dat1 dat2 dat3 | tr " " "\n" | xargs -I {} -p ln -s {}' | grep -oP '(^|\| *)\K[^ ]*'
echo
tr
xargs
```

Note, `echo ... | command` is better written as `command <<< ...`. See JID's comment for more details.

Comment: Don't need the echo can do `awk '{print $1}' RS='|' <<< 'echo dat1 dat2 dat3 | tr " " "\n" | xargs -I {} -p ln -s {}'`

Comment: ^^ Agreed. but I thought that the `echo ... | tr ... | xargs ...` command line OP received was from some command like `history`.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** The best option would be to use `awk`, but since you stated that you can't do that, here's two other solutions:

**Option 1: For loop and `cut`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

data='echo dat1 dat2 dat3 | tr " " "\n" | xargs -I {} -p ln -s {}'

IFS="|"

for l in ${data}; do
    echo $l | xargs | cut -d ' ' -f 1
done
```

**Explanation**

Set the internal field separator to the `|` character, so that the `for l in` separates along these lines.

Then each line is passed through `xargs` solely to remove leading white spaces, and finally put into `cut` which cuts along spaces and returns the first item it sees.

**Option 2: sed**

First convert the `|` plus as many spaces as you find after them into newlines, then delete everything from the first space in each (new) line:

```
echo ${data} | sed -e 's/|[[:space:]]*/\n/g' | sed -e 's/[[:space:]].*$//'
```